# Is there a way to prevent background of a parent element from showing up on the edge when both parent and child have a border radius?

Tags: css

So let’s say we have a div inside another div; both the parent and child divs have the same border-radius, and the child’s width and height are 100% of the parent’s. If the parent has a background different from the child’s, a thin line of this background will be visible around the round corner of the child:

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Here is an example on CodePen: http://codepen.io/azangru/pen/MKdQmG

And the code itself:

HTML:

```
<div class="dark-bg">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="inner">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.dark-bg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  background: black;
}

.outer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.middle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Is there a way to prevent the parent’s background from showing up from behind the child (without removing the parent’s background completely I mean)?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: I want only the child’s background to completely hide the parent’s background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  .inner {
     border-radius: 8px;
  }
```

Why? http://www.mrgeek.me/technology/tutorials/web-design/css3-border-radius-property-explained/

See it working:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrmQeG

Comment: It worked on the test example, so I guess it’s a correct answer, but it did not fix the problem I am seeing in the codebase I am working on. I have a bad feeling that I will actually have to resort to JavaScript to remove the parent’s background if a child also has a background :-(

Comment: Ok, a part of my problem also was that I had overflow: hidden on the parent element in my work code :-) Now that this property is gone, your solution works perfectly!